# Mixing in a trait into a test method in ScalaTest using fixture.FlatSpecLike

Tags: scala, scalatest, scalikejdbc

When using `ScalaTest`'s `org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike`,  I can create a Fixture and mix it into the test, as follows:

```
class Foo extends FlatSpecLike with Matchers {

  trait Fixture {
    val bar = 2
  }

  "This test method" should "not cause a compile error" in new Fixture {
      2 shouldEqual bar
  }

}
```

However, when I use `org.scalatest.fixture.FlatSpecLike` instead, I cannot do this:

```
class Baz extends fixture.FlatSpecLike with Matchers {

  trait Fixture {
    val bar = 2
  }

  "This test method" should "cause a compile error" in new Fixture { implicit session =>
      ...
  }

}
```

Could someone suggest how I can mix in a trait into a test method with `fixture.FlatSpecLike` ?

UPDATE:

Here is the error from the compiler after I run `~test:compile` in `SBT`:

```
in new Fixture { implicit session =>
[error]                                                                                                                          ^
[error] one error found
[error] (Test / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

Intellij shows something like `Type mismatch, expected () => Any, actual: Foo.this.Fixture with Object { ... }`

Comment: I guess, when you say, "you cannot do this", what you really mean, is that you are getting an error from the compiler. That error, probably, contains a message, that would tell you what you are doing wrong, if you took a moment to read it ...

Comment: @Dima: I did read it the compiler error. The compiler error is uninformative, though the intellij error is infomative. I have updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: Sigh. Show your entire code, and the complete error message.